# The parameter in the callback function of ''.query'' method is undefined on my response

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, ejs

I am connected to my MySQL database, but when I am using the `.query` method and I write the callback function with the "error" and "result" parameters, I do not have the result of my query in the browser when I use or "res.send (result)". The console shows `undefined` when I use `console.log(typeof result)`. what do I need to do so that my parameters are recognized by the callback function so that I can get the result of my query in the browser?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('engine views', 'ejs')

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    const mysql = require('mysql')

    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password:'password',
        database: 'database'
    })


    connection.query('SELECT * FROM database_table', function(err, result){
        res.send(result)    //problem
    })
})

app.listen('3000', function(){
    console.log('Server ON')
})
```

I expect the result of my query in JSON format in the browser when i access `localhost:3000`, but I have a blank page.

Comment: check if there's any error

Comment: check the network tab in the dev too, and the preview tab, what are the status code? is it 409?

Comment: status code: 304